# Rectangle animation examples

Tags: silverlight

Are there any examples on the internet of silverlight animation which can do the following:

A rectangle zooming in
A rectangle going down from a certain position on the x axis to a certain position on the x axis

I looked on silverlight.net but couldn't find these examples (which are quite rudimentary). Anyone know where I can see an example with source for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a ScaleTransform for the zooming effect and Translate transform for the move effect. I am sure you can find out lot of examples in a search for "Silverlight Animation". It doesnt matter it is rectangle or any other UIElement

http://www.wynapse.com/Silverlight/Tutor/Clipping_Silverlight_Animated_Rectangles.aspx
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/7303/have-you-seen-the-silverlight-more-silverlight/2/